# Display elements of associative array on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have four `div` elements and I have four elements in my array. I'd like to get something like this:

When user makes a click on first `div` element(`class .news`), "values" of the first element of array are displayed inside of `div #selectedNews`.

[Here's my code](https://jsfiddle.net/qqyvu3dm/2/)

My problem is that I don't understand how to associate div and array elements.

Code again:

```js
var newsListData = [
  {
     "group" : "science",
     "title" : "Text 1",
     "image" : "images/news1.jpg",
     "content" : "Text text text"
 },
 {
     "group" : "science",
     "title" : "Text 2",
     "image" : "images/news2.jpg",
     "content" : "Text text text"
 },
 {
     "group" : "science",
     "title" : 'Text 3',
     "image" : "images/news3.jpg",
     "content" : "Text text text"
 },
 {
     "group" : "economics",
     "title" : 'Text 4',
     "image" : "images/news4.jpg",
     "content" : "Text text text"
 }]




var selected;
function elem() {
  selected.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
    selected.appendChild(this.children[i].cloneNode(true));
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var selectedNews = newsListData​ /* stuck HERE */
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedNews.length; i++) {
    selectedNews[i].addEventListener("click", elem);
  }
  selected = document.getElementById("selectedNews")
});
```

```css
#selectedNews {
  border : 1px solid gray;
  margin : 10px;
  padding : 5px;
}

.news{
  background-color : green;
  border : 2px solid black;
  padding : 4px;
  margin-top : 2px;
  text-align : center;
}
```

```html
<div id="newsList">
<input type="text" placeholder="filter..." id="filter"/> 
 <div  class="list"> 
 <div id="0-news" class="news">One</div>
    <div id="1-news" class="news">Two</div>
    <div id="2-news" class="news">Three</div>
    <div id="3-news" class="news">Last one</div>
    

<article id="selectedNews">
 <h1>Titre</h1>
 <figure> 
  <img src="" alt="titre"/>
 </figure>
 <div id="content">
  bla bla
 </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the index of the array item you want to display. I'd do it by attaching an event listener to the `.news` elements, like this:

```
<div id="0-news" class="news" onclick="display(0)">One</div>
```

And in your JS

```
window.display = function(index) {
    var data = newsListData[index]; // get the right data from the array
    ...
}
```

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/qqyvu3dm/4/

EDIT Create the buttons from your data in a loop:

```
  var newsList = document.getElementById("newsList");
  var button;

  for (var i = 0; i < newsListData.length; i++) {
    // create button element in memory
    button = document.createElement("button"); 

    // set id attribute
    button.setAttribute("id", index + "-news"); 

    // attach event listener, pass i as pointer to your array element
    button.onclick = display(i); 

    // append the button into #newsList div
    newsList.appendChild(button);
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much! Is it possible to make a loop in my case or it's useless?

Comment: yes, a loop to generate the buttons would be a better approach

Comment: thanks! but I don't understand what's "selectedNews" now

Comment: oops, should be newsListData. the point is that for each item in newsListData, you create a button that corresponds to that item